# Sammy routing not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sammy.js

I'm using Sammy routing on an ASP.NET MVC web app, based originally on the standard MS template for a SPA web app, which uses Knockout and Sammy to manage page loads/routing.  I'm new to Sammy so I don't understand it well, but my expectation is that the /#search route would be executed, even if it's the first page load, but it seems like it is not.  The "/" route is always executed on a 'cold' page load.

Basically, if I run the app in Debug mode, all works perfectly fine.  The #home and #search routes work as expected. But if, while debugging, I paste this URL into a new tab or browser session:

http://pr-dev.dav1.net.fmcti.com/#search/101-4155

Then, rather than the /#search route code executing, it appears that the "/" route code is executing.  Does this route always execute upon a new session, regardless of the #search term being present in the url?  Here is the typescript code in my home page viewmodel where the SPA routing is configured:

```js
        // configure SPA routing
        Sammy(function () {
            this.get("#home", () => {
                if (app.view() !== self) {
                    // load page view model
                    app.view(self);
                }
                // clear out any search results
                self.hideResults();
                self.queryTree.refreshDataSource([]);
                self.partSummary(new SR.PR.Query.QueryResult());
                self.searchBox.setValue("");
            });

            this.get("/", function() {
                this.app.runRoute("get", "#home");
            });

            this.get("#search/:pn", function() {
                if (app.view() !== self) {
                     app.view(self);
                }
                const pn = this.params["pn"];
                if (pn) {
                    SR.PR.Query.doPartSearch(self, pn.toUpperCase());
                } 
            });

        });
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When using the hash, try defining the routes with `'#/<the_path>'` instead of `'#<the_path>'`. See more examples in the documentation: http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes
I think that will fix your problem.

But if the '/' route continues to be executed first, try to define it in the last position.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt suggestions.  This was not my problem, as it turns out, but it certainly helped me understand it better.  I will post my final solution separately.

Answer (score 1):

This issue turned out to be a problem with another area in the code.  In the main app viewmodel's init function, I was calling the #home route function.  In addition, elsewhere I had mistakenly called this init function *before* the ko.applyBindings function.  It all works better once I switched around the order.